# Fixed Action Buttons not working properly?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to learn Materialize (materializecss.com) and I am stuck with how to make action buttons. The button on the lower left hand corner appears, but when I hover, the other buttons do not then appear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <div class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
            <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
            <li><a><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added `materialize.js ` file because after adding js in your code its working fine for me

Comment: No, that's not working. Where did you add the js file in your code? I've tried materialize.js and materialize.min.js in the body section. Should I put it in the head?

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: No, there isn't any error.

Comment: after adding jquery it works for me see my snippet below in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added jquery in code and its working fine for me,
See my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
       <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
            <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
            <li><a><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Kindly provide some explanation to your code.. Only code answer(s) are not acceptable, even though if it works for the OP..